# Do all SQL flavors share a base query language and type set?

Tags: sql

For example if you take MySQL, PostgreSQL, MSSQL and SQLite. Do they all share the same exact language for select, insert, update, delete? Do they all share a base set of types like mediumint, text and varchar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a clear SQL [standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), which all compliant SQL implementations should comply.

See this [comparison](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/), of the different things that each database implements.